# How can I alter the breadcrumbs on a search page?

Tags: theming, breadcrumbs

I just enabled search on my Drupal theme and when I go to the search page my breadcrumbs show like this:

> home > Search > Content > Search

Is there any way to make it just:

> Home > Search

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For ease of use you might want to look at [Path breadcumbs](http://drupal.org/project/path_breadcrumbs):

> This module is a solution for all problems with the breadcrumbs on
>   your site!
>
> Path breadcrumbs module helps you to create breadcrumbs for any page
>   with any selection rules and load any entity from the URL!

There is also [Custom Breadcrumbs](http://drupal.org/project/custom_breadcrumbs) which was pretty awesome, but be careful if you choose this route as there is [serious discussion about deprecating it in favour of Path breadcrumbs](http://drupal.org/node/1823080).

[Hansel Breadcrumbs](http://drupal.org/project/hansel) is useful, but I have found it INCREDIBLY complicated to get set up and working properly. I would suggest to use it only if you're going to be setting up a lot of complicated rules. If it's just for one or two pages, it's probably overkill and might end up making you hate Drupal (and no-one wants that!) ;-)

Answer (score 2):

## Search Page Breadcrumb Trail:

home > Search > Content > Search

Make these highlighted changes in your active theme's template.php

```
function THEMENAME_breadcrumb($variables) {
  $breadcrumb = $variables['breadcrumb'];
  if (!empty($breadcrumb)) {
    $output = '<h2 class="element-invisible">' . t('You are here') . '</h2>';

    if(arg(0)=='search')
    {
      unset($breadcrumb[2]);
      unset($breadcrumb[3]);
    }

  $output .= '' . implode(' » ', $breadcrumb) . '';

  return $output;
  }
}
```

## Result:

Home > Search

Like entries:
[https://drupal.org/node/2151655]

Answer (score 1):

Try out [Hansel breadcrumbs](http://drupal.org/project/hansel) module.

> provides custom breadcrumbs which are build by user defined rules.
>   These rules are independent from the menu system. Rules can have logic
>   switches and can add links to the breadcrumbs.

Answer (score 1):

There are different [breadcrumb customizing modules](https://drupal.org/node/533448) available for Drupal 7. They all have their own configuration or APIs. Which one you choose for a given site probably depends on more criteria than just the breadcrumbs on the search page - so choose wisely. As Binu pointed out, you can even do this without any breadcrumb-customizing module.

In this answer I am going to explain how to do this with [Crumbs](https://drupal.org/project/crumbs) 7.x-2.0-beta12 (or up).

There is an [issue for Crumbs asking for nicer search breadcrumbs](https://drupal.org/node/2151655), and a basic support for this has actually been implemented in Crumbs 7.x-2.0-beta12 natively!

If you are not happy with this, you can get more creative with hook_crumbs_plugins():

```
/**
 * Implements hook_crumbs_plugins().
 *
 * @param crumbs_InjectedAPI_hookCrumbsPlugins $api
 */
function MYMODULE_crumbs_plugins($api) {

  // The $key is needed so the user can configure a weight for this "plugin".
  // The plugin will be available in admin/structure/crumbs as
  // "MYMODULE.search.content.parent" ("MYMODULE." is always prepended)
  $key = 'search.content.parent';
  // Make <front> the parent of search/node/%.
  // Obviously this could be any parent path, your choice.
  $api->routeParentPath('search/node/%', $key, '<front>');

  // And now let's change the title of the search breadcrumb element.
  // This needs a new $key, so it can be sorted separately on admin/structure/crumbs.
  $key = 'search.content.title';
  $api->routeTitleCallback('search/node/%', $key, function($path, $item) {
    return t('Search for @terms', array('@terms' => $item['map'][2]));
  });
}
```

Troubleshooting / Notes:

- Most of the changes to hook_crumbs_plugins() need a flush-cache to have any effect.
- In admin/structure/crumbs/display there are settings that allow you to hide the current page, or that will hide the breadcrumb if it consists of too few elements. These settings can result in your MYMODULE stuff to be totally hidden.
- Go to admin/structure/crumbs and make sure your new plugins get a high enough priority. The easy way is to simply move MYMODULE.* to the top.
- Obviously, MYMODULE needs to be replaced with your own custom module name.